# javascript loading sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a MainView "About.cshtml" it has a script tag in it and a partial view.

```
<script>
    $(function () {}
</script>
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", Model.saVM)
</div>
```

Inside "_MapDetailList.cshtml" partial view i am referencing another script ge.js

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ge.js")
<table id="MapDetails">
      .....
  <tr><th>
    <script>setGrowthArray(1, 1);</script>
  </th></tr>
</table>
```

**ge.js**

```
var dictionaryGrowth = new Array();

function setGrowthArray(colIndex, mapDetailId) {
//making a sparse array
dictionaryGrowth[colIndex] = mapDetailId;
}
```

Now i want to send this dictionaryGrowth array to server side after the page/table is loaded

so i did the following in the About.cshtml script but didnot work..

```
<script>
    $(function () {
   $("#MapDetails").load(function () { alert("everything seems fine");});
  }
</script>
```

Also please tell me what will be the script and DOM loading sequence in my case.

**UPDATE**
Probably the Current sequence is

1. Script on About.cshtml is executed
2. ge.js is executed
3. document.ready inside partial view is fired
4. javascript function (setGrowthArray) from inside DOM is called
5. Now i want to call my controller??
   If i write window.onload = ... inside ge.js it is never fired

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute using `$.post()` for `.load()`, pass result of `setGrowthArray(1, 1)` as data posted to server

```
<script>
$.post("/path/to/server", {growth:setGrowthArray(1, 1)}, function(data) {
  console.log(data); // response from server
  $("#MapDetails").html(data);
})
</script>
```

Comment: do i also need to mark the server side action in controller as  [HttpPost]

Comment: At server check for `POST` request where key is `"growth"`

Comment: pls see my update..now it says Uncaught ReferenceError: dictionaryGrowth is not defined in both $.post and $(document).load

Comment: What is purpose if `$(document).load()` call?

Comment: or should i use window.onload? so dictionaryGrowth is not undefined..m not sure though

Comment: What is result when you use `<script>` element? `<script src="~/Scripts/ge.js"></script>` ? Is path to `ge.js` correct?

Comment: no i am not using ge.js in about.cshtml..in this page i only use a script tag and write <script>$(function(){});</script>

Comment: which executes when? and am i able to access the variables defined in ge.js which is included in the partial view?